# How to connect to selenium grid using password and username?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-grid

I have that code for grid connection later I want to test some basic page, but Im stucked with basic auth for grid connection how can be HOST not Specified error when there is a HOST:

```
browser = webdriver.Remote('https://username:password!@selenium.tools.grid.io/wd/hub',
                           options=options)
desired_capabilities={
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "browserVersion": "latest",
        "video": "True",
        "platform": "LINUX",
    
    })
```

but I got an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scratches\scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\-tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 79, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 325, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\tests-v2\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 231, in connection_from_host
    raise LocationValueError("No host specified.")
urllib3.exceptions.LocationValueError: No host specified.
```

Can someone could help me?